# iOS: replace an object inside an array of array

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios, nsarray

My code is:

```
[[arrayOne objectAtIndex:indexSelected] replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:new];


NSLog(@"indexSelected:%d", indexSelected); // = 0
NSLog(@"new:%@", new); // = 26
```

`indexSelected` is an int and `new` is a string

When I try to do this I have an exception that says: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cee60'`

Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because NSArray is immutable.  Use an NSMutableArray.

Comment: Toll-free bridging does not mean what you appear to think. Simply casting an NSArray to NSMutableArray will not work.